# Potential bug - incorrect view post

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I'm sorry if meta isn't the proper place to post bug reports (please correct me if it's not!). But I recently added a question and it was upvoted. But it's saying there are 0 views of the topic:

[image]

Is it possible to upvote a question without actually viewing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a caching issue and will go away. Additionally the appropriate place to report such bug issues would be here for the time being. Bug reports can be migrated from here later.

Comment: Ah, cache makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Yeppers. Additionally, it's pretty well only going to _really_ be seen while things are getting ramped up. It'll really not be noticable once there's more volume. But that page is cached pretty heavily since it's seen way more frequently.

Comment: It's [buffered, not cached ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43751/133693)

Comment: Huh, I thought it was cached. Go figure.